# Scanner class: Two inputs on the same line, seperated by spaces

Tags: java

In the following piece of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class A
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        int b = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

If I input the two numbers in one single line (separated by spaces) after the first message is displayed, both are taken as input simultaneously and then the second message is displayed.  Why is it so?

Comment: That is what the code does, gets the next 2 inputs as integers, it does not matter if they appear on the same line or not.  You can also enter one, next message pops up, and enter the other.  Can you clarify why you are confused by this?

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` gives you the next input irregardless if the inputs are on the same line or not.

To get only the first value of each line you can use `sc.nextLine()` in between calls to `sc.nextInt()` to consume the line terminator and move to the next line:

```
System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
int a=sc.nextInt();

sc.nextLine(); //Place this to ensure other inputs on same line don't matter

System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
int b=sc.nextInt();

//Without the nextLine it will set c to the next int even on same line as b

System.out.println("Enter the third number: ");
int c=sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
System.out.println("c = " + c);
```

**Test Run:**

```
Enter the first number: 
1 2 3 4 5
Enter the second number: 
78 89 99
Enter the third number:
```

**Output:**

```
a = 1
b = 78
c = 89
```

As you can see, the scanner will only set `a` to `1` and ignore `2 3 4 5`, then wait for the next input for `b` on the next line and set `b` to `78`.

However, `c` will be set to `89` because the `scanner` was not told to move on to the next line, and then the print statement will be run afterward without an option to enter anything.

Comment: Sorry for replying late,   my confusion is that during runtime, even if the first next() function reads both the inputs at once, then why the second next() function is not called after the second message to read an input again?

Comment: The first next only reads a single input, it does not read both at once.  It is calling both `nextInt()` at the same time because it sees there is a value to grab that is available.

Comment: I see..but why are both the next() functions called at once,  isn't the program supposed to execute one line after another sequentially?

Comment: What I am trying to say is, is it the first call to next() that reads the input for b or is it the second one? Or, is the next() even called a second time?

Comment: It is the second one.  It IS done sequentially, it just does not wait for your print statement to do it.  It sees the value so it takes the value, doesnt matter where and doesnt matter if you print between.

Comment: Is it that,  when we give an input THEN the next() is called    OR   when the next() is called then we can give the input?

Comment: It may help to read some of the java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read exactly how it works

Comment: It looks for whitespace as a default from where the Scanner was left off, and there are ways to get the input first and ways of giving it second.  Test different stuff to understand it better

Comment: I am confused about all this ! haha,  anyway,  thanks for staying with me this long 